# Do reviewers auto-suggest to close as "needs more focus" when multiple question marks are present?

Tags: discussion

I've been bothered by this issue for a while, but this question ([Should I normalise image pixel wise for a pretrained model](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/82088/should-i-normalise-image-pixel-wise-for-a-pretrained-model)) in particular made me think that this might be the case.

The question can be summed up to "should I normalize images pixel-wise?", but the asker had the misfortune of adding "All I can think is ... Am I missing something?", which looks like another question if you don't read it.

And it has 4 votes to close as "Needs more focus" (i.e. multiple questions in one).

Am I in the wrong here? Do this question need more focus? If not, is there a larger issue here, and what can we do?

Comment: Another example here (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/82530/help-with-type-of-ml-problem-when-training-data-is-spread-across-different-subg): OP asked "my question are: How to solve my problem? What is it called? Are there examples for it?". It already has a close vote.